# Content Editor Web Part blank in jQuery slideshow

Tags: jquery, css, content-editor-web-part

Now I dont get any error(s). But the content editor wp is blank (well, except for the gear image). Any idea(s)??

```
<IMG ID="slideshowPicturePlaceholder" src="/_layouts/images/GEARS_AN.GIF" style="display:none"/>
<style type="text/css">
/*--Main Container--*/
.main_view {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
/*--Window/Masking Styles--*/
.window {
    height:286px;   width: 790px;
    overflow: hidden; /*--Hides anything outside of the set width/height--*/
    position: relative;
}
.image_reel {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0;
}
.image_reel img {float: left;}

/*--Paging Styles--*/
.paging {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 40px; right: -7px;
    width: 178px; height:47px;
    z-index: 100; /*--Assures the paging stays on the top layer--*/
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 40px;
    background: url(paging_bg2.png) no-repeat;
    display: none; /*--Hidden by default, will be later shown with jQuery--*/
}
.paging a {
    padding: 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
}
.paging a.active {
    font-weight: bold;
    background: #920000;
    border: 1px solid #610000;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
}
.paging a:hover {font-weight: bold;}
</style>
<center><div id="slideshowContentArea" style="display:none; width:255px;">    
<div class="main_view">
    <div class="window">
        <div class="image_reel">
         </div>
    </div>
    <div class="paging">
        <a href="#" rel="1">1</a>
        <a href="#" rel="2">2</a>
        <a href="#" rel="3">3</a>
        <a href="#" rel="4">4</a>
    </div>
</div>

</div></center>

<script type="text/javascript" src="_layouts/jquery/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

    function GetAllImages()
    {
       $("#slideshowPicturePlaceholder").css("display", "block");
       var soapEnv = "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'><soapenv:Body><GetListItems xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/'>";
       soapEnv += "<listName>NewsList</listName>";
       soapEnv += "<query><Query><OrderBy Override='TRUE'><FieldRef Name='Created' Ascending='FALSE' /></OrderBy></Query></query>";
       soapEnv += "<viewFields><ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title'/><FieldRef Name='ows_FileLeafRef'/><FieldRef Name='NewsLink'/><FieldRef Name='Description'/></ViewFields></viewFields><rowLimit></rowLimit>";
       soapEnv += "</GetListItems></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>";

       var port = window.location.port;
       if (port.length <= 0)
       port = "";
       else
       port = ":" + port;
       var webservice = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname + port + L_Menu_BaseUrl + "/_vti_bin/lists.asmx";

       $.ajax(
       {
          url : webservice,
          type : "POST",
          dataType : "xml",
          data : soapEnv,
          complete : processQueryResults,
          contentType : "text/xml; charset=utf-8",
          error : function (xhr)
          {
             alert('Error!  Status = ' + xhr.status);
          }
       });   
    }

    function processQueryResults(xData, status)
    {
       var port = window.location.port;
       if (port.length <= 0)
       port = "";
       else
       port = ":" + port;
       // Change the below to point to your image library
       var imageURL = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname + port + L_Menu_BaseUrl + "/Splash Image Rotator/";
       var itemURL = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.hostname + port + L_Menu_BaseUrl + "/Splash Image Rotator/Forms/DispForm.aspx?ID=";

       // $("#slideshowContentArea").html("")
       $(xData.responseXML).find("z\\:row").each(function ()
       {
          var title = $(this).attr("ows_Title");
          var headlines = $(this).attr("ows_Description");
          var imageLink = imageURL + $(this).attr("ows_FileLeafRef").substring($(this).attr("ows_FileLeafRef").indexOf('#') + 1);
          // // var itemLink = itemURL + $(this).attr("ows_ID");
          var itemLink = $(this).attr("ows_NewsLink");
          var liHtml = "<div><a href='" + itemLink + "' target='_blank' border='0'><img width='200' height='200'  src='" + imageLink + "'/></a><p align='center'>" + title + " - " + headlines + "</p></div>";
          $("#image_reel").append(liHtml);

          // Show the paging and activate its first link
          $(".paging").show();
          $(".paging a:first").addClass("active");

          // Get size of the image, how many images there are, then determin the size of the image reel.
          var imageWidth = $(".window").width();
          var imageSum = $(".image_reel img").size();
          var imageReelWidth = imageWidth * imageSum;

          // Adjust the image reel to its new size
          $(".image_reel").css(
          {
             'width' : imageReelWidth
          }
          );


        // Paging  and Slider Function
        rotate = function ()
        {
           var triggerID = $active.attr("rel") - 1;
           // Get number of times to slide
           var image_reelPosition = triggerID * imageWidth;
           // Determines the distance the image reel needs to slide

           $(".paging a").removeClass('active');
           // Remove all active class
           $active.addClass('active');
           // Add active class (the $active is declared in the rotateSwitch function)

           // Slider Animation
           $(".image_reel").animate(
           {
              left : - image_reelPosition
           }
           , 500);

        }
        ;

        // Rotation  and Timing Event
        rotateSwitch = function ()
        {
           play = setInterval(function ()
           {
              // Set timer - this will repeat itself every 7 seconds
              $active = $('.paging a.active').next();
              // Move to the next paging
              if ($active.length === 0)
              {
                 // If paging reaches the end...
                 $active = $('.paging a:first');
                 // go back to first
              }
              rotate();
              // Trigger the paging and slider function
           }
           , 7000);
           // Timer speed in milliseconds (7 seconds)
        }
        ;

        rotateSwitch();
        // Run function on launch

        // On Hover
        $(".image_reel a").hover(function ()
        {
           clearInterval(play);
           // Stop the rotation
        }
        , function ()
        {
           rotateSwitch();
           // Resume rotation timer
        }
        );

        // On Click
        $(".paging a").click(function ()
        {
           $active = $(this);
           // Activate the clicked paging
           // Reset Timer
           clearInterval(play);
           // Stop the rotation
           rotate();
           // Trigger rotation immediately
           rotateSwitch();
           // Resume rotation timer
           return false;
           // Prevent browser jump to link anchor
        }
        );

       });
       }

GetAllImages();
});

</script>
```

Comment: Have you confirmed your webservice call comes back ok with the data you need in it?

Comment: yes: web services is bringing data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have

```
<div class="image_reel">
```

But then you try to access element, as if it was `id="image_reel"`

```
$("#image_reel").append(liHtml);
```

You have to use class as in other places:

```
$(".image_reel").append(liHtml);
```

Comment: You are correct. After changing it your suggested code I can now atleast the image. However, I only see part of the 1st image. I dont see page numbers and pictures that should slideshow.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that you don't see any content because you never show() the `slideshowContentArea` div (it's hidden by your inline CSS).

Add the following at the very end of the `processQueryResults` method:

```
$('#slideshowContentArea').show();
```

Comment: Agreed. I don't see any other references in the code for `#slideshowContentArea`

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I have now added show to this div and hiding the busy image div. However, firebug still coming up with this error $v_0 is null
[Break On This Error] var $v_1 = $v_0.parentElement();  and there for magic is happening.